# Como colocar uma .gem no Gemfile

Tags: gem, ruby

Boa tarde, estou com um problema ao instalar uma .gem através do Gemfile. No Gemfile está:

```
gem 'hanaclient', path: '/usr/sap/hdbclient/ruby/hanaclient'
```

Dentro do **/usr/sap/hdbclient/ruby/hanaclient** (ls):

```
hanaclient-2.3.119-x86_64-linux.gem
```

Ao executar o **bundle install**, retorna:

```
Could not find gem 'hanaclient' in source at `/usr/sap/hdbclient/ruby/hanaclient`.
The source does not contain any versions of 'hanaclient'
```

Alguma solução? Obrigado.

Comment: Foi adicionado a versão da Gem no arquivo Gemfile `gem 'hanaclient', '2.3.119', path: '/usr/sap/hdbclient/ruby/hanaclient'`, e o problema foi solucionado, porém obtive um outro problema que aparentemente, mesmo instalado, a Gem não consegui ser carregada quando tento dar um **require 'hanaclient'**: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- hanaclient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo pois está apontando para um arquivo `.gem`, e ele deve ser desempacotado. Portanto:

```
gem unpack my_gem.gem --target app_path/vendor/gems
```

Depois de desempacotado, é só referenciar no `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'my_gem', :path => 'vendor/gems/my_gem'
```

> Só uma nota: Você está tentando listar uma gem local no `Gemfile`. Geralmente isso gera problemas entre diferentes ambientes e não é recomendado.

Comment: Perfeito, resolveu o problema! Obrigado! :D